# Terraform recreates BQ Dataset access resource every time there are changes in the plan

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, terraform

I manage my BQ infrastructure through Terraform.
I recently found out about the [google_bigquery_dataset_access](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/bigquery_dataset_access) resource, which can be used to either grant access to a dataset to every resource of a specific type, or individually grant access for views.

So I implemented this in my `foo` dataset module

`dataset.tf`:

```
resource "google_bigquery_dataset_access" "dataset_authorization" {
  dataset_id = "foo"
  dataset {
    dataset {
      project_id = "some-project"
      dataset_id = "bar"
    }
    target_types = ["VIEWS"]
  }
}

module "foo_dataset" {
  source  = <path to google provider google_bigquery_dataset>
  version = "some_version"

  dataset_id  = "foo"
  description = "lorem ipsum"
  location    = "some_location"
  project     = "some-project"

}
```

But every single time there is a change anywhere in my configuration (not even just in this foo module), TF plan says there's been changes to the access resource and it will try to recreate it:

**Terraform apply output**

```
# module.foo.module.foo_dataset.google_bigquery_dataset.dataset has changed

  ~ resource "google_bigquery_dataset" "dataset" {
      ~ etag                            = "VH7HJLt5Avl4zcT1spXxtA==" -> "ZQFENhnM/wOpJrgaccOfgQ=="
        id                              = "some-project:foo"
      ~ last_modified_time              = 1667311213019 -> 1667312336825
```

The `etag` and `last_modified_time` change even if no changes were done on the module.
Does anyone know what might be going on here?

Comment: Filed a bug at the upstream project: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-google/issues/14001